# CURSOR and REF CURSOR as a JDBC data type

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ref-cursor

Many RDBMS support "CURSOR" types of some sort. Those types are mostly useful when returned from stored procedures. An example in Oracle:

```sql
TYPE t_cursor_type IS REF CURSOR;
CREATE PROCEDURE p (c OUT t_cursor_type);
```

When calling this procedure using JDBC, the `OracleTypes.CURSOR = -10` "JDBC" type should be used. This type is not part of any standard and it is not going to be part of JDBC 4.1 in Java 7.

Does anyone know whether the JSR guys will consider adding this type to the standard some time in the future? Or if other RDBMS have a similar "vendor-specific type"?

Comment: Yeah especially considering that pretty much every DB does have cursors. While I also only have used Oracle, a quick google search for <db> cursor shows results for: MSSql, MySQL, postgre and db2. Only sqlite (not that surprisingly) doesn't seem to have them..

Comment: @Voo, even H2 supports "cursors" in function results...

Answer (score 7):

Support for REF CURSORS was added in Java 8/JDBC 4.2.  Use the type [`Types.REF_CURSOR`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html#REF_CURSOR) for cursor return types.  They can be iterated through the `ResultSet` interface.  Example:

```
CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{callmySproc(?)}");
cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.REF_CURSOR);
cstmt.executeQuery();
ResultSet cursor = cstmt.getObject(1, ResultSet.class);
while(cursor.next()) {
    System.out.println("Name = " + cursor.getString(1));
}
```