# Save and return multiple rows within function pl/sql oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, function, plsql

```
declare
    type t_trayIds is table of number(38,0) index by binary_integer;
    v_trayIdsTable t_trayIds;
create or replace function F_getTrayIdByDiameter(v_diameterInCm tray.diameterincm%TYPE)   
return t_trayIds
as 
    v_trayIdsTable t_trayIds := null;
begin
    select t.trayid into v_trayIds from tray t 
    where t.diameterincm = v_diameterincm;
    return v_trayIdsTable;
end;
```

So what I want is, to ask for all Tray IDs with a specific Diameter and store them in an Array or Table. In Java I used ArrayList. I want to return the Table in the end to pass the result onto another function. The above code doesn't seem to work. SQL Developer gives me a syntax error at the word `create`.
Can someone help?

Comment: You can use a ref cursor also, depending upon the data size that is returned refcursor is efficient. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56288998/using-a-ref-cursor-to-retrieve-a-resultset-with-java-program-is-throwing-an-erro

Comment: If the end result of your function can be a "Table", why do you need PL/SQL for this at all? Whatever can use the rows from your output "Table" should be able to consume the same rows from a trivial SQL `SELECT` statement, why are you messing with arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code fails because you are mixing a **declare** section that must be followed by a **begin** section, with a "create or replace function" that is a standalone statement to create objects;

If you want to declare a PL/SQL table type and make it public,
you must put it in a package specification, so it can be visible by any function (I also declare here the function F_getTrayIdByDiameter, to make it visible):

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE package utils is
        type t_trayIds is table of number(38,0) index by binary_integer;
        function F_getTrayIdByDiameter(v_diameterInCm tray.diameterincm%TYPE) return t_trayIds;
    end utils;
    /
```

besides, you can't use SELECT INTO syntax, because

> select col into var

can be used only for single row, not for lists;
in PL/SQL, if you want to manage multiple rows, you have to use a cursor;
so, if you want to create your PL/SQL table, you can fetch your cursor and build your list (PL/SQL table);
so, your package body can be,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE package body utils is
function F_getTrayIdByDiameter(v_diameterInCm tray.diameterincm%TYPE) return t_trayIds is 
    v_trayIdsTable t_trayIds;
    i number := 0;
    cursor c is 
    select t.trayid from tray t 
    where t.diameterincm = v_diameterincm;
begin
    for my_rec in c loop
        v_trayIdsTable(i) := my_rec.trayid;
        i := i + 1;
    end loop;
        
    return v_trayIdsTable;
end;
end utils;
/
```

Then, you can use your list in another function, or in an anonymous block, just for example:

```
declare
  my_result utils.t_trayIds;
begin
  my_result := utils.F_GETTRAYIDBYDIAMETER(20);
  dbms_output.put_line(my_result(0));
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

By starting with `declare` you are creating an anonymous block, which do not have return values. They just do stuff and quit. It sounds like you want to create a function instead.

First, to return a collection of `trayids`, you need to create a type to return. This has to be done at the schema level; it is an object in its own right. There are three kinds of collections in Oracle: nested tables, associative arrays ("index by" tables), and varrays. I pretty much never use varrays and I don't think you can use associative arrays like this (but I forget, this may have changed in recent versions of Oracle). So create your type:

```
create or replace type t_trayids as table of number;
```

Now create your function. The key here is you must use `bulk collect` to populate the array. This is *vastly* faster than creating a result set and looping over it.

```
create or replace function F_getTrayIdByDiameter(v_diameterInCm tray.diameterincm%TYPE)   
    return t_trayIds
as 
    v_trayIdsTable t_trayIds;
begin
    select t.trayid bulk collect into v_trayIdsTable from tray t 
    where t.diameterincm = v_diameterincm;

    return v_trayIdsTable;
end;
```

As Nicola points out, you can also create a package and declare the type inside the package specification. You can use associative arrays this way. Which approach depends on what you're trying to do.